# vender problems: found packages text (doc.go) and transform (examples_test.go) in my vender

Tags: go

I got some problems:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hL58q.png)
`..\vendor\github.com\spf13\afero\util.go:28:2: found packages text (doc.go) and transform (examples_test.go) in D:\golang\src\services\vendor\golang.org\x\text \transform`

How can I solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Do not post screenshots of what can and should be copied and pasted as (formatted) text. [Here's how to copy and paste text in a Windows console window](https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-copy-and-paste-windows-command-prompt.htm) in case you are not familiar with it yet. The reason is that text on images is not indexed by search engines and hence cannot be found by the next person having your exact problem.

Comment: sry, I ask question for the first time.@kostix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `doc.go` has moved from the dir `golang.org/x/text/doc.go` to `golang.org/x/text/transform/doc.go`.

This means the transform directory has two packages in it.

Here you can see the package files for `text`, just `doc.go`
https://github.com/golang/text/tree/master

And here are the files from transform: https://github.com/golang/text/tree/master/transform

Delete the `doc.go` file from `golang.org/x/text/transform`